# Loss of synchronicity with RxJs Angulat 16

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the code from the service

There are 2 requests in it

The first one

```js
tap(([ question,examOrTestId ])=>{
          if (mode && examOrTestId && question?.id) this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.actions.postDataRequest({
            mode,
            test: examOrTestId,
            question: question.id,
            answer: answerId,
          });
        }),
```

It works fine
But there's a second one.

```js
this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.actions.getDataRequest('theory-result', null, examOrTestId);
```

There is already a problem with it, which is that for some reason it fires after the whole pip after (finalize).

[Here's how it's done Where 0 is the subscription code itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buv8Z.png)

Full Code

```js
    this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.selectedQuestionId
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        filter(
          (selectedQuestionId) =>
            selectedQuestionId !== null && selectedQuestionId !== undefined,
        ),
        switchMap((questionId) =>combineLatest([
          this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors
            .selectQuestionById(questionId as Question['id'], mode as Mode)
            .pipe(
              take(1),
            ),
          this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.examOrTestId
            .pipe(take(1),
              filter((testOrEamId) => !!testOrEamId),
              map((testOrExamId) => this.examAndTestUtil.checkValueToStringType(testOrExamId),
              ),
            ),
          this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.totalFailureQuestionsAndAnswers$
            .pipe(
              take(1),
            ),
          this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.selectedExamAndTestLatestState
            .pipe(
              take(1),
            ),
        ])),
        tap(([ question,examOrTestId ])=>{
          if (mode && examOrTestId && question?.id) this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.actions.postDataRequest({
            mode,
            test: examOrTestId,
            question: question.id,
            answer: answerId,
          });
        }),
        switchMap(([question, examOrTestId,totalFailureQuestionsAndAnswers, examAndTestLatestState]) => {
          return this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.questionsAndAnswers.pending$.pipe(
            filter(pending => !pending),
            take(1),
            switchMap(() => this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.selectNextQuestionIdByCurrentQuestionId(question?.id as Question['id'], mode).pipe(
              take(1),
              map(nextQuestionIdData => ({
                question,
                examOrTestId,
                nextQuestionIdData,
                totalFailureQuestionsAndAnswers,
                examAndTestLatestState,
              })),
            )),
          );
        }),
        tap(({ examOrTestId, nextQuestionIdData } )=>{
          if (nextQuestionIdData.isLatest) {
            this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.actions.getDataRequest('theory-result', null, examOrTestId);
          }
        }),
        switchMap(({ question, examOrTestId, nextQuestionIdData,totalFailureQuestionsAndAnswers, examAndTestLatestState }) => {
          return this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.mistakes.pending$.pipe(
            filter(pending => !pending),
            take(1),
            switchMap(() => this.examAndTestFacade.questionsAndAnswers.selectors.totalMistakes$.pipe(
              take(1),
              map(totalMistakesQuestionsAndAnswers => ({
                question,
                examOrTestId,
                nextQuestionIdData,
                totalFailureQuestionsAndAnswers,
                examAndTestLatestState,
                totalMistakesQuestionsAndAnswers,
              })),
            )),
          );
        }),
        finalize(()=> console.log('finalize'))
```

If you ask the ultimate question, why is the query executed after everything?

I've tried using different rxjs parameters.
exhaustMap
mergeMap
withLatestFrom and map
race

But there were no changes in the work, the query still executes after finalize